# Is it possible to use AWS Amplify to upload a file to a presigned URL that was generated on server?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

After reading the documentation I see that it's possible to upload a file like this:

`Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(key: fileNameKey, local: filename)`

but the S3 bucket is hardcoded in the Amplify config file.

Our current design without Amplify generates signed URLs in our private server and sends those to our mobile app.  Can we pass those URLs to Amplify?